# How to let vim listchar work under not utf8 environment?

Tags: vim

My .vimrc contains:

```
if $LANG =~ '\(UTF\|utf\)-\?8' || $LC_CTYPE =~ '\(UTF\|utf\)-\?8'
  set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
endif
```

But there is some chars which is unicode, when I run vim under LC_CTYPE=zh_TW.Big5 environment, it will show

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.vimrc:
  line   70:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:»·,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line to your vimrc, preferably near the beginning:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```

That will tell vim to read the file as UTF8 even if you're on a non-UTF system.  It will then transcode any characters from that into your current encoding.  If the characters you're using in the listchars option exist the other encodings that you use you shouldn't even need to have the conditional around that.

Comment: This method works on vim, but, I found gvim still shows that error message.

Comment: Do you have a `.gvimrc` file that also contains unicode characters? If so, adding the same line to that file should fix the problem there as well.  That command only applies to the file in which it is found, so would need to be included in any vim configuration file where the character encoding is important.

Comment: I found the problem caused by my gvimrc and fixed it.